# Alert about DB creation on RDS/Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have some Aurora PostgreSQL Clusters created on our AWS account. Because of some access issues (which we are working on already), there are several people in other teams who create random DB's on these Aurora Clusters and then we need to work on cleaning them up.

I wanted to check if there is a way to get alerted (via SNS Notifications etc.) whenever a new DB is created on these AWS Postgres clusters using some AWS Tools itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using AWS Aurora Database Activity Streams, it will capture all database activity on the database and send it AWS Kinesis Data Stream and you could create a AWS Lambda function to read Kinesis Data Stream and identify the events needed (ex. create database)and finally send notification to AWS SNS from AWS Lambda code.

Another option is enable pgaudit on your AWS Aurora PostgreSQL, send logs to AWS CloudWatch, create AWS Lambda to read the events from AWS CloudWatch and send AWS Notification

Below you can find step by step on AWS Blog below.

[Part 2: Audit Aurora PostgreSQL databases using Database Activity Streams and pgAudit](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-2-audit-aurora-postgresql-databases-using-database-activity-streams-and-pgaudit/)